# Crystal Reports 2013 Group selection based combinated content

Tags: crystal-reports, selection

I have been searching for while but I have not found a similar question.

I have a database including all offered positions to customers. 
I need to figure out in which offer we offered article A **together** with article B.

Therefore I started to Group my data by **offer#**. And now I need to find a solution how I can select all Groups/offers which includes article A and B.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a suppress condition on group header, details and group footer as:

```
if offered article ="A" and offered article = "B"
then false
else true
```